# Running MPI program on two hosts with different login ids

Tags: mpi

I'm having access to two linux machines. On machine A, my user name is abc and on machine B, my user  name is pqr. ssh acceess is open from Host A to Host B. How can I run a MPI program from host A that makes use of host B processor as well? (specifically is there a way I can specify the remote user name in hostfile?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to specify a user name in the host files simply `user@adress` should work, also remember you need password less SSH or rsa for the mpi functionality to work